# How to enable arrow keys on vim used from msysgit bash

Tags: windows, bash, keyboard, vim, git

I just need a simple solution that will enable the arrow keys in the vim included with Git For Windows. I did found a solution to enable backspace. But no solution for the arrows problem. The arrows work on bash but not on vim.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You can'T navigate the cursor with the arrow keys on your keyboard?

Comment: yes. the arrow keys do not work/ hjkl work but are useless in insert mode. Not a big problem as is only on vim on git-bash. But an anoyance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way. If someone else has the problem.

in /etc/vimrc

You need to use the Ctrl-V key (deactivate it from ConEmu first if using it)

then write

```
set t_ku=(Ctrl-V,Up Arrow Key)
set t_kd=(Ctrl-V,Down Arrow Key)
set t_kl=(Ctrl-V,Left Arrow Key)
set t_kr=(Ctrl-V,Right Arrow Key)
```

note than 
(Ctrl-V,Up Arrow Key)
Means press Ctrl-V then press the Up Arrow key

You will see something in the lines of

```
set t_ku=^[A
set t_kd=^[B
set t_kr=^[C
set t_kl=^[D
```

Where ^ is the Escape character (27) instead of ^